# WPF VB.net - Can multiple CommandBindings be executed for the same command?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, routed-commands, focusmanager

In WPF I'm trying to use commands to set all the content in multiple textboxes at once. The following code is able to get a command on the toggle button to execute for which ever textbox has scope but I can't seem to get the command to execute for both at the same time.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" Width="20" Height="20"></ToggleButton>
    <RichTextBox Width="200" Height="200">
        <RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding 
                        Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" 
                        Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
        </RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
    </RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox Width="200" Height="200">
        <RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding 
                        Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" 
                        Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
        </RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
    </RichTextBox>
</StackPanel>

Private Sub CommandBinding_Executed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
    DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox).SelectAll()
    DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox).Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontWeightProperty, "Bold")
    e.Handled = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandBinding_CanExecute(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)
    e.CanExecute = True
End Sub
```

Is what I am trying to do possible with commands? I would prefer not having to make direct references to each textbox in code behind inside a click_event or anything like.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reference the parent container, and look through it's children for a specified type, then perform your action on the child object providing it is the type you want.

Something like

```
foreach(var child in MyRootPanel.Children)
{
    if (child is RichTextBox)
    {
        // Process whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Great idea!